# CMD Assigning variable to file name in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a way to assign a filename to a variable based on a wildcard. This is what I have so far:

```
cd Y:\FileLocation\FileName1.txt

For %%a Y:\FileLocation\FileName1*.txt
Set Claims= %~nI
```

Not sure if you can point to a file and grab the attributes from that specific file and assign the file name. Or how I can go about doing this. I do need to use the wildcard since the file name can have a datestamp, but the root of the file name will always remain the same.

Comment: What's not working about your code so far?

Comment: %%a was unexpected at this time,
and the variable Claims = %~nI not the file name as i am looking for.

Comment: try typing `help for` at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is this syntax:

```
 For %%a IN (D*.lnk) DO Set Claims=%%~na
```

So to change your code to match what works, it would read...

```
cd /d "Y:\FileLocation"
For %%a IN ("Y:\FileLocation\FileName1*.txt") DO Set "Claims=%%~na"
```

Changes I made were:
1) Added key-word "IN"
2) Added parenthesis around file specification
3) Added key-word "DO" and removed the new-line
4) Changed your "%~nI" to "%%~na"

Comment: Just commenting that the `cd` command is not needed in this case.

Comment: When I try this I get the error: %%a Was unexpected at this time. 

Also when I try and call the Variable to test if it works, will the following work: Echo Claims?  Or do I need to call it %Claims%

Comment: You probably got, "..unexpected at this time" because you executed the code from a command prompt, instead of from within a .bat file.  To execute from the command prompt, remove one of the two "%"s in each of the two places you see "%%", to make the line read:  
For %a IN ("Y:\FileLocation\FileName1*.txt") DO Set "Claims=%~na"

Comment: Brian: 'Claims', in "Echo Claims" would require "%"s, e.g. "Echo %Claims%".  As such, you're still calling it 'Claims', but enclosing it in "%"s. References to environment variables in DOS batch are (must be) enclosed by "%".